# PHP Database output. Arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

In first case, i will get full array:

```html
   <?php

   $servername = "localhost";
   $username = "root";
   $password = "";
   $dbname = "test.com";


   $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

   if (!$conn) {
       die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
   }

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE writer='$w_name' ";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


   if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo $row[header];
       }
   }
   mysqli_close($conn);

   ?>
```

In the second case, i will get just 1st value from array:

```html
   <?php

   $servername = "localhost";
   $username = "root";
   $password = "";
   $dbname = "test.com";


   $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

   if (!$conn) {
       die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
   }

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE writer='$w_name' ";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


   if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $q=$row[header];
       }
   }
   mysqli_close($conn);

   ?>

<div>
  <? echo $q ?>
</div>
```

What should I do, to make 2nd case work like 1st? I mean, how to put into $q, all values of array, not just the first.

Comment: It is defined in other part of code.

Comment: Your usage of mysqli_num_rows($result) is pointless in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not defining `$q` as an `array` at all.

```
$q=array();
...
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $q[]=$row['header'];
}
...
```

an example of output :

```
foreach($q as $header) {
   echo $header.'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting $q . Try using $q[]=

Answer (score 0):

change `$q=$row[header];` line to `$q[]=$row[header];`

and then not `echo $q;` but `print_r($q);`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this into the while

```
$q = array();

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            array_push($q, $row['header']); // i guess header is a column of the table
       }
}
```

and then you must have your array when print the `$q` variable, i mean do an `print_r($q)`

More info about array_push: http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-push.php

Hope this helps :)

Comment: if header is already defined your code won't work. Because php will not interpret it as a string.